# Is this the best way to initialize an array object using a constructor?

Tags: c++

One suggested using assert, but it won't be helpful for the user because this kind array can be created and resized during runtime. So, I think exceptions are better suited. While this is for my own educational purposes, this specific portion helps me understand initialization better. I'm always confused on how to best initialize using constructors because I can't return true/false here.

Right now the idea is to use exceptions. I'm wondering if this is the best way and what other things I should consider. Overall, is this the best way to initialize an array object using a constructor?

```
Array(const int size)
{  
    // Validate size.
    if (size <= 0)
        throw std::invalid_argument("Size must be greater than zero.");

    try {
        m_array = new (std::nothrow)T[ob.m_size];
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc &e) {
        throw e;
    } 

    m_size = size; 
}
```

**Current code:**

I got rid of internal std::nothrow and internal throwing. Instead, I'm now only checking with the outer scope. My thought is this is cleaner. As long as the user knows what exceptions to check for in the documentation, I feel this is a good approach at the moment.

```
try
{ 
    Array<int> a(10);

    con.writeLine("Size: %llu", a.getSize());

    a.resize(100);

    con.writeLine("Size: %llu", a.getSize());
}
catch (std::bad_alloc &e)
{
    con.writeLine("Caught something terrible: %s", e.what());
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `std::vector` ?

Comment: Who made std::vector? What is it doing underneath, and how can you optimize it if your platform implementation is slow? It all starts with the array. As I said, it's for my own educational purposes.

Comment: Indeed you're supposed to use exceptions for failures in constructors. If for some reason you can't, your only option is to have a special failed state for your object. Of course this is for educational purposes only, you should NEVER manage memory in your actual code (use `std::vector`)

Comment: I'm reading a book on data structures. std::vector is used later. If you're dependent on what STL provides, I guess that's fine 99% of the time. But of course STL doesn't provide you everything, so you need to still learn how to manage memory.

Comment: @Bob if your platform implementation of `std::vector` is slow you should probably file a bug to your compiler provider. `std::vector` is specifically desined for exactly that task (runtime-resizable contigous array) so it definetly should not be slower/worse than your code

Comment: Yeah, bad example. Still, again, this is for educational purposes.

Comment: (1)  it doesn't make sense for the `size` to be an `int`.   An `unsigned` type would be better, and using that would eliminate the need to check for `size <= 0`.  A zero size is fine.    (2) Initialise `m_array` in the constructor's initialiser list, using the throwing form of `new`.   If an exception is thrown in working through a constructor's initialiser list, the standard guarantees appropriate cleanup.   That is not so if an exception is thrown in the constructor body.

Comment: Incidentally, using the STL is a sensible default choice.   It has been specified by professionals (in developing the standard).   It is implemented by professionals, and subject to scrutiny of developers, unless you're using a really obscure compiler/library.  A significant majority of developers would over-estimate their ability to implement their own array (or whatever) properly, and then fail to implement it in a way that beats the STL - in terms of design, quality of implementation, etc.  For beginners, the chances of over-confidence coupled with likelihood of failure approach 100%.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. For the fourth time tonight, it's for learning purposes.

Comment: It makes no sense to call `new` with `nothrow` but then manually throw `bad_alloc`

Comment: @Bob, please ignore the people who are suggesting you abandon your education in favor of taking a pre-made solution. Go ahead and learn why `vector` is built the way it is so that when you use it in a real program, you are using a tool you've mastered.

Comment: @VTT Is the above what you had in mind? Switched the std::nothrow for an embedded try/catch block.

Comment: This is even worse, specifically asking for `nothrow` and still trying to catch a exception which can never happen, only to rethrow it, in the worst possible way. Just replace that whole try-catch-block with `m_array = new T[size];`.

Comment: The point of `nothrow` is to avoid overhead of exception throwing when allocation failure could be handled on sight. So throwing `bad_alloc` when `nothrow` is used makes no sense. Placing `try..catch` block makes even less sense. Just leave the regular `new` invocation.

Comment: @JaMiT Thanks. I wish to be a competent C++ programmer. For example, I found that adding by chunks on a private resize is more efficient than std::vector's size*2 during private resizing. If you had 1000 items in std::vector, and it resizes internally, that's going to be 2000 items just because of that one item you just inserted. With mine, it just increased by adding a small chunk (30 or so). Which is more efficient? When you (anyone in general) are called to write a data structure to meet a specific need, you begin to think of these things and how they can be more efficient than STL.

Comment: Why do you think adding specifically 30 is more efficient? If I eventually add 2000, your implementation will cause 66 reallocations, while std::vector will cause only 10.

Comment: Last thought too is it was C++ programmers who made STL. You might be called one day, or you can just say you're fine with what has been handed to you. Most .Net developers are fine that way, too.

Comment: It's great to try to understand how things work, but your assumption that the c++ experts that develop STL just haven't given much thought to making things efficient sounds arrogantly naive.

Comment: @Rotem, "arrogantly naive" is one possible interpretation. Another is "not accepting things just because others said so". Questioning why things are the way they are is a good way to learn. (I might chime in on the performance, but it's probably better to stick to the initialization question here.)

Comment: @JaMiT No argument there, but this is not questioning, this is saying "my implementation is better because I declare that `+30` is better than `*2` for all cases. " Without tests, profiling, proof, what added value does the user learn from this?

Comment: Updated code above.

Comment: You should be using `size_t` as the size type. It's right there in the name :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo There you are... lost your comment. Yes, size_t is a good choice for a 64-bit environment, as it's an unsigned long long.

Comment: For those interested: I'm surprised with measuring my complete array vs std::vector. For assigning 1000000 items, I'm getting 43ms for Array and 232ms for std::vector. With shuffling in the middle of each of these above using <algorithm>, I'm getting 285ms for Array and 404ms for std::vector. I'm just starting a few simple benchmarks, but so far it seems like std::vector is a little more weightier than my lighter array class.

Comment: This makes me wonder why some of you thought this academic attempt wasn't worthwhile. I'm getting faster results than relying on some prebuilt class. This doesn't always seem to be the case, as sometimes vector might be faster than my own, or near equivalent. As always though, measure and use the better data structure for your requirements, and don't be afraid to make your own! :) I learned a lot and got some nice results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an unrecoverable<sup>[1]</sup> error condition, an exception is reasonable. Be sure to document the conditions under which your constructor throws. However, better than detecting an error condition is to prevent an error condition from occurring in the first place. Have the compiler detect errors, rather than checking things at run time (when possible).

For example, you allow a negative number to be passed in for the size, but then you reject it. Better would be to prevent the negative from being passed in the first place. It would be a good idea to change `size` from an `int` to an `unsigned`.

That leaves the zero case. Why is it so bad to create a zero-length array? If you want to throw an exception in that case, you could, but I would suggest support for zero-length arrays. You may find that it requires no special logic, which would give you extended functionality for free.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> This of course means "unrecoverable within the class", as it is not reasonable to expect most classes to know what sorts of errors the program can recover from.

Comment: In case of *unrecoverable* error condition only a call to `abort` is reasonable. Exception is reasonable when error could be potentially recoverable but error handling is delegated to unspecified calling code.

Comment: @VTT I mean a condition from which the constructor cannot recover, but that the program as a whole might recover from. Failure to allocate memory is one example. I thought the context would make this clear, but apparently I made a poor word choice. What adjective would you use instead of "unrecoverable" to get this point across?

Comment: Just an added thought: One thought right now is get rid of the throwing in the constructor in the body and just test for it in the outer scope: try { Array arr(10); } catch (std::bad_alloc e) { } for example.

Comment: I wouldn't use any adjective, "exception in case of error condition is reasonable".

Comment: Good thought. size_t is a unsigned long long, but yes, that does save some typing and remembering. (Not sure where his comment went with suggesting size_t, as it's not a bad idea in a 64-bit environment instead of using an unsigned int).

Comment: @Bob - `size_t` is only guaranteed by the standard to be an unsigned integral type.   It is not guaranteed to be a `unsigned long long` or any other particular type.

Comment: I think that's true for any integral data type. Although unsigned int is always a 32-bit integer on Windows, on other platforms it may be whatever the executing environment specifies. I guess this is a case of 'know thy platform'? Unless you're saying even though it's compiled as an unsigned long long, it's still not guaranteed to be an unsigned long long on a non-64-bit platform. Either way, I haven't seen a 32-bit platform for a while.